# Caching Raster Imagery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I HAVE 6 Separate raster images for which i created a raster dataset. I am trying to cache this imagery to increase display performance.  How do you cache a raster dataset in arcmap?

Comment: What GIS app. would you like to use for caching rasters?

Comment: I intend to use an Arcgis Online GIS Mapviewer. However, it'll be using Arcmap for the creation of the cache.

Answer (score 1):

In caching the Raster Dataset in ArcGIS online. go to File, save a service definition file, choose available service, continue , service editor. Look for 'Caching' on the service editor. you have two options in caching, 'Dynamically from data' and 'using tiles from cache'. 
Selecting 'using tiles from cache' will give you the benefit to select a maximum or minimum scale level for the tile.

Going for this option for high performance, i will suggest you look at areas of highest interest for users depending on what you want to achieve.